# Typescript Class and Interface highlighting in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript, syntax-highlighting

How can I define the colors of the syntax highlighting of typscript classes and interfaces in Visual Studio 2013 Update 4? I can't find it in the items list of Fonts and Colors.

The Hello World looks like:

[image: Syntax highlighting of Typescript]

I would prefer, if Greeter, HTMLElement and Date would look like in C# :)

**Update:** The Roslyn based Language Service is doing well. But only in VS 2015 Preview. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2014/11/12/announcing-typescript-1-3.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It's not available in VS2013. According to the TypeScript development team [the semantic colorization for colorizing types is only available in VS2015](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1200).